# Why am I urged to include my source files via files[] instead of using include_once?

Tags: .info

What is the reason of using the .info file to declare the files used from the module, instead of including them at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Writing .info files (Drupal 7.x)](http://drupal.org/node/542202):

> Drupal now supports a dynamic-loading code registry. To support it, all modules must now declare any code files containing **class** or **interface** declarations in the .info file (...). When a module is enabled, Drupal will rescan all declared files and index all the classes and interfaces that it finds. **Classes will be loaded automatically by PHP when they are first accessed**.

So it only makes sense to add a file to the files[] array, if that file contains declarations of classes or interfaces and is not included manually (e.g. by calling [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7)).

Comment: But how is this useful, I mean?  I can just do 'include_once' like normal, can't I?

Comment: It can lower the memory footprint to only load things if they are actually used for a particular page.

Comment: Or to put it even more clearly; if you have an .inc file listed in files[] which contains classes, that file will automatically be loaded from disk *only* if that class is used; otherwise, it won't be loaded. This is a performance improvement.